# Calculating Percentage from fake group

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

How do I calculate the percentage in the value accessor? I thought I would be able to just add the grouped value and divide it then multiply it to get the percentage?

```
var fakeGroup = {
                top: function() {
                return [
                    votes.top(Infinity).reduce(function(a,b) {
                    if(b.value > 0) {
                      a.value += elecVotesMap.get(b.key)
                    }
                    return a
                  }, {
                    key: "",
                    value: 0
                  })
                ]
              }
            }


        percentElec
        .group(fakeGroup)
        .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
        .valueAccessor(function(){ return fakeGroup / 538 * 100; })
```

Comment: Put a console statement in your valueAccessor and I suspect you'll be able to see what you need to do: `.valueAccessor(function(d){ console.log(d); return fakeGroup / 538 * 100; })`  It will be something like `.valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value / 538 * 100; })`

Comment: It now displays a 100% value when all states are selected, but when selecting individual states it knows the amount of electoral votes for that state but the number display isn't updated with the % calculation so the number box is left blank. Not sure why it wouldn't work since as it knows 538 votes is 100% and other values are being given.

Comment: Got it, was just because of it returning a value that wasn't whole. Thanks

Comment: Cool. If you want to post the end result, people will probably find it helpful in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After adding Ethans suggestion the code still wouldn't print due to the decimal formatting being incorrect as it was return values such a 7.33. Once I changed that the number displayed worked perfectly.

code:

```
percentElec
        .group(fakeGroup)
        .formatNumber(d3.format(".2f"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d){ return d.value / 538 * 100 ; })
```